# Velocity Addition and Length Contraction in Special Relativity(data insufficient?)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

> A train of length 300m observes another train on a parallel track coming towards it at v = √ 3/4c. The other train appears (i.e. is measured by the first train) to have a length of 300 m also. In the reference frame of the second train, how long does it take for the two trains to pass each other (i.e. what is the time between when the fronts align and when the backs align)?

I understand I have to find speed of train1 with respect to 2 and use the Lorentz transformation for time. But how do I find the speed? The speed of the train1 nor the real length of train 2 is given.

Comment: You can assume the speed of train 1 to be 0 in his system.